# python script placement in apache

Tags: python, apache, centos7

This would lead to a more nvolved question, but I could use some help with such things as search terms to use to find more info, links (someone has already done this, etc.).
First of all, lets assume a centos7/apache/mod_wsgi serverset up.
    Lets also assume no django, no nginx, no bootstrap,no php, possibly not even a database.
    (That should narrow things down quite a bit).
    I want to use 2 or 3 python scripts (maybe more), but 3 main ones.
    Now, let's say I have an html page with a button,a href that calls a python script. What choices do I have on where to put this script? Right in the apache root directory, the cgi-bin, somewhere else? And let's say this button and script takes the user into a protected directory (the same script - is that possible?). And hooks up to another python script that does some math - maybe random numbers, and leads to another python script that sends the user somewhere else - another html page? Sorry, this is pretty vague - which is why I'm asking the question - need more info.  And I think this also applies to security, a lot of these questions and answers are very outdated. Where's the best place to place python scripts in apache?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a start: https://www.linux.com/blog/configuring-apache2-run-python-scripts.

Once you've got it running, take the next step (i.e. adapt your python code to do what you want it to do).

Does that help you to take a step towards your goal?

Comment: Thanks, that would be the standard method.  Are there any other methods for doing it?

Comment: Certainly. The web contains a lot of informations on different methods on how to do it. However it's up to you to read that up, to consider which method you need and why and to try them out.

Comment: I was trying to get a discussion going on not only the methods, but also security - see if anyone else noticed that a lot of this is out-of-date.  You offer one method only and then try to shut it off.